# URL of images and files in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

When  I add image or script file without adding **"http:localhost:xxxx/"** at the beginning of the URL it doesn't work. but when I add it is work fine. why this happened although the URL is correct.
e.g:

`Styles/Images/ModalDialogAlert.gif`   .... **worong**

`http:localhost:xxxx/Styles/Images/ModalDialogAlert.gif` .... **correct**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to start with a slash: /Styles/Images/ModalDialogAlert.gif

Comment: This will be domain root relative, instead of virtual application root relative. If they host their site on `/MyApplication` then the URL ends up being `/Styles/Images/ModalDialogAlert.gif` instead of `/MyApplication/Styles/Images/ModalDialogAlert.gif`. That's why it's more appropriate to use the `~/Styles/Images/ModalDialogAlert.gif`, so it will handle being hosted in a virtual application without making any modifications.

Comment: yes, you can use the ~ trick to make it relative to your application regarthless the host domain.

Comment: It's not a "trick". It's essential to having virtual root relative paths.

Comment: I didn't ment to call it "trick" like it was a hack or something. In fact it is the way to do it. Its just that Idk the "~" name, so I call it trick

Answer (score -1):

you can use a dot before url to address from this directory or double dot for parent directory

it's like http://yourDomain/directories/Styles/Images/ModalDialogAlert.gif

```
    <img src="./Styles/Images/ModalDialogAlert.gif"/>
```

and it's like: http://yourDomain/parentDirectories/Styles/Images/ModalDialogAlert.gif

```
    <img src="../Styles/Images/ModalDialogAlert.gif"/>
```

Comment: `../` does not mean root directory. It means "go up one directory. That's a relevant path and usually something to be avoided.